# InvalidPipeArgument: '333,00' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'?

Tags: angular

I have this in template :

```
 <input class="ui-g-4 right"  [ngModel]="product.itemamount | number:'1.2-2'" (ngModelChange)="product.itemamount = $event">
```

But im getting this error when i change value in input.

> InvalidPipeArgument: '333,00' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'

Any suggestion?

Comment: what is `product.itemamount`, what type of values are you adding, also add your pipe what you doing there, you cant expect help without giving anything

Answer (score 2):

From Angular [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#how-to-use):

> Formats a number as text.

You cannot use DecimalPipe on `<input>` tag. Like the following:

```
<p>  {{product.itemamount | number: '1.2-2'}} ></p>
```

To make the formatting of an input you have to write a custom pipe/directive/method, etc..

**UPDATE:**

Here is some idea of a custom validation directive:

**HTML**

```
  <input decimal [(ngModel)]="value" name="value" >
```

**Directive**:

```
HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onInput($event){
  let formattedValue: string;
  let arrayValue = this.el.nativeElement.value.split('.');

  let patternValidation = arrayValue[0].match(/[0-9]{3}/);

  if (patternValidation !== null && arrayValue[0].length > 3) {
    let thousands = Array.from(Array.from(arrayValue[0]).reverse().join('').match(/[0-9]{3}/).join()).reverse().join('');
    let replacement = arrayValue[0].replace(thousands.replace(/\D/g, ''), '');
    formattedValue = (replacement.length > 0 ? replacement + "," : "") + thousands;
  } else {
    formattedValue = arrayValue[0];
  }

  if (arrayValue.length > 1) {
    formattedValue = formattedValue + "." + arrayValue[1].substring(0, 2);
  }

}
```

[**Stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmvqg9?file=app%2Fdecimal-mask.directive.ts)

Comment: You may find this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41821711/5468463

Comment: i need input so that i can change that value ... i dont want only to display it.

Comment: One of the options could be to make a second property as the model of your input and update the property that you want on (change) or something like that. You will still need a custom pipe.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/8yU6OLvTU5kQloJfc7pG?p=preview u see here does not need custom pipe

Comment: The DecimalPipe is NOT intended for the use in <input> tags, it's not that it works partially that you will get it work. You need a custom formatter as above.