# Angular 2: Formatting numbers in input fields in IE 11

Tags: html, angular

I'm working in IE 11 browser and I want to restrict the input number field to 3 digits with 5 decimal places. I tried the following

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="amount" maxlength="3" />
```

The problem I face is it will allow me to add only 3 digits with no decimals. I tried to add pattern but in IE its not supporting (Angular-2.4). How to handle this?

Comment: [`pattern` is indeed supported in IE11](https://caniuse.com/#search=pattern). It's standard HTML5. BTW, this question has nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: @torazaburo input type number does not work in IE 11. It allows to enter characters as well. Need do write keypress event. What say?

Comment: `pattern="\d{1,3}\.\d{5}"` doesn't work? `type=number` works all the way back to IE10.

Comment: Its not working + allowing me to enter characters too

Comment: you can achieve this using directives. refer this answer with max votes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465542/angular2-input-field-to-accept-only-numbers and change as your requirements