# Key event filtering for numbers, letters or other groups

Tags: javascript, angular, keyboard-events, eventfilter

Angular4 docs shows ( [Key event filtering (with key.enter)](https://angular.io/guide/user-input) ) how to catch keyboard keystrokes events easier - `(keyup.enter)="foo()"` or `keyup.w` or `keyup.space` etc.

What I need is to fire event only if letters being pressed.

One way I can think of is:

`<input id="textFilter" (keyup)=“foo($event)”>`

```
  foo(e){
    var allowedKeys = [‘KeyQ’, ‘KeyW’, ‘KeyE’, and the rest of the alphabet...]
    if (allowedKeys.indexOf(e.code) != -1 ) {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

But I would expect such `pseudo-events` already build-in in Angular. For ex. for letters, like - `(keyup.letters)="foo()"` and for numbers, like -`(keyup.numbers)="foo()"`. Are there any? And is that solution above is preferable for filtering keyboard keystrokes by groups?

[docs](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/8fa1539bacd454635d1f78ab056e2017929d0634)

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there are no keyup groups provided by angular. But you can easily create custom directive to allow/disallow your own set of keys.

Here's a [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41479077/5556177,%20you%20can%20find%20custom%20directive%20to%20only%20allow%20numbers) of allowing letters only.

only-letters.directive.ts:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[onlyLetters]'
})
export class OnlyLetters {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @Input() onlyLetters: boolean;

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
    let e = <KeyboardEvent> event;
    if (this.onlyLetters) {
      
      // console.log(e);
      
      if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+C
        (e.keyCode == 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+X
        (e.keyCode == 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
          // let it happen, don't do anything
          return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (((e.keyCode < 65 || e.keyCode > 90)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
  }
}
```