# How to allow only numbers in html input type text using TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I have a HTML textbox. How to allow only numbers in it on keypress event?
There is a `type=number` however I have use type text.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41479077/1791913

Comment: why you need text box? if only accepting numbers.

Comment: Why do you have to use type text? Who or what is forcing you to?

Answer (score 2):

You can use "keypress" event in your text input. You can use this function.

---

```
<input id="example" type="text" [(ngModel)]="example" (keypress)="OnlyNumbers($event)" />
```

---

```
public OnlyNumbers($event) {
let regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{1,}$/g);
let specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowRight','ArrowLeft'];enter code here
if (specialKeys.indexOf($event.key) !== -1) {
  return;
} else {
  if (regex.test($event.key)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's works but you can prefer the directives for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#component-class-1) in your component and for allowing only numbers in input field you can use `Validators.pattern("^\\d+$")` like minlength, required validations are handled in this form.

Answer (score 0):

> HTML:

```
<input type="text" (input)="onTextboxChangeValidate($event)">
```

> TS file include below function

```
onTextboxChangeValidate(event: Event)
{
var inputData = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;

//replace more than one dot
var extractedFte = inputData.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace('.', '')
  .replace(/\./g, '').replace('x', '.');

//Extract nuber Values
extractedFte = extractedFte.replace(/^(\d+)\d*$/, "$1");

//Reasign to same control
(<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value = extractedFte; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain what your code does, otherwise user with the same problem wount be able to learn of your solution.

Comment: Actually i wrote function for restrict 2-decimal values from that i derived above one.
We can use same function for allow decimal values for slight modification.
See below two examples u can understand.
for allow only 2 decimal value -
https://arulkumarsivaraj.blogspot.com/2020/06/allow-2-digit-decimal-value-from-001-to.html

Allow only numbers:
https://arulkumarsivaraj.blogspot.com/2020/06/allow-2-digit-decimal-value-from-001-to.html

Comment: Actually written regx for allow one dot, for only number no need that so replaced with empty.

//replace more than one dot


                    inputData.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace('.', 'x') -> it will extract numbers and dots from that we replace first dot with x.
  .replace(/\./g, '') -> it will remove other dots
  .replace('x', '.') -> again replace x to Dot