# HTML text input allows only numeric input in angular 2

Tags: angular

**html file**

```
<input type="text" size="10" onkeypress="return numbersOnly($event)">
```

**component.ts**

```
public numbersOnly(event) {
  return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57;
}
```

I don't why my code not work! Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: `(keypress)="eventHandler($event)"` is the standard event handler

Comment: It's work. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

use the Angular DOM event emitter `keypress`

```
(keypress)="eventHandler($event)"
```

Is the standard event handler. You can implement a method this way.

It's also useful to note that all the HTML5 standard DOM event emitters work this way in Angular, `onthisevent` -> `thisevent` e.g. `onkeypress` -> `(keypress)`, `onblur` -> `(blur)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you just change the type as number?

```
<input type="number" size="10" >
```

Comment: My project request type is number.

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: @Nguyenhuyen_AG if you need a directive look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465542/angular2-input-field-to-accept-only-numbers

Answer (score 1):

what is the point of using type="text" if you want to type number.If you only need to type number use type="number" here you don't want to write any function to restrict keys.use as below

```
<input type="number" size="10" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
</input>
```

or

as Sajeetharan mentioned, HTML5 now also support input with type number

Comment: I know your solution but I want create function, because in my project have many input number. Thank you.