# How do I allow only numbers and special characters in my input?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have this:

```
  <input style="text-align: right;font-size: 12px;" class='input' (keyup.enter)="sumTotal($event)" type="text"
      [ngModel]="field.value" (focusin)="focusin()" (focusout)="format()" (keyup.enter)="format()"
      (ngModelChange)="onlyNumbers($event);field.value = $event;sumTotal($event);" [disabled]="disabled">
```

In my ts i have this:
I want numbers and special characters.

```
  onlyNumbers(letter) { if (letter.toUpperCase() !== letter.toLowerCase()) { return; } else { this.field.value = letter; } }
```

But it still can enter letters. Any suggestion?

Comment: use `type="number"`

Comment: i cant number because it can be enter 3,00 2.00 , 2.000,00 and so on

Comment: Then explain your question better, what do you mean when you say  `I want numbers and special characters.` what special character you want to allow, which not. and why not , .

Comment: i write that already in my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - Input Field To Accept Only Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465542/angular2-input-field-to-accept-only-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) by checking if [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) returns `false` and if its not a `.` or `,` could be a solution for you:

```js
function numbersonly(e){
  if(isNaN(e.key) && e.key !== '.' && e.key !== ',') e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="numbersonly(event)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
 onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 && event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"
```

other way set pattern

```
 pattern="[0-9]"
```

Comment: i still can enter characters

Comment: then try to set a pattern.