# Angular Input Type PASSWORD and NUMBER

Tags: html, angular

How do I make my input field only accept numbers (don't allow ANY letters to be inputted) and also hide the inputted values? It is taking a sensitive number. This also needs to keep the max and minlength validation at 4.

Here is what is not working:

```
<input matInput type="password" pattern="[0-9]*"  minlength="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="Last Four of SSN" formControlName="ssn" required>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 - Input Field To Accept Only Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465542/angular2-input-field-to-accept-only-numbers)

Comment: No, need to hide inputted values, accept only numbers, and have a min and max length set to 4.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex for your pattern

```
[pattern]="'^[0-9]{4}$'"
```

Comment: This works BUT stops allowing maxlength="4" to work.

Comment: I think this is very close but: ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[0-9]{4,4}*$/: Nothing to repeat

Comment: I was wrong: <input matInput type="password" [pattern]="'^[0-9]{4}$'" maxlength="4" placeholder="Last Four of SSN" formControlName="ssn" required> IS NOT working.

Comment: That gives the error: ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[0-9]*{4}$/: Nothing to repeat

Comment: This pattern means you can have digits and exactly `4` character length.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to set also the angular validator for this form field (own validator or pattern validator)