# How to create a Validator.pattern that accepts ONLY numbers

Tags: angular, regex, typescript, validation, customvalidator

I am working on an angular project, and I am trying to ensure that an input field only accepts positive integers between 1 and 28, however the regex I have tried is not marking the form field as invalid when letters are entered.

Here is my code:

```
setDateRegex = /^[0-9]*$/;

. . . 

scheduleSetDaysBefore: [null, [Validators.max(28), Validators.min(1), Validators.pattern(this.setDateRegex)]],
```

I have also tried the following regular expressions, and none of them are working.

```
/^[0-9]+$/

/^[0-9]+(\.?[0-9]+)?$/
```

And a few others I cannot remember.

**EDIT**

I just wanted to add, I have already achieved something similar by using a `Valdidator.pattern()` to check that an email has been entered in an acceptable format, as well as various length validators.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465542/angular2-input-field-to-accept-only-numbers) and there are many more, doesn't anything work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maybe use a [custom validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators), something like this

```
// i have multiple custom validators so I am using them in a separate file.
export class CustomValidators {

  static isNumbers(control: AbstractControl) {

    if (!(control.value)) {
      return null;
    }

    return String(control.value)
      .match(/^[0-9.]+$/) ? null : {'isNumbers': true};
  }
}
```

In your formBuilder, include this

```
scheduleSetDaysBefore: [null, [Validators.max(28), Validators.min(1), CustomValidators.isNumbers]],
```

And in your HTML, you can check for this error, apply invalid class on control maybe or show message

```
<span class="error-message" *ngIf="form.get('scheduleSetDaysBefore').getError('isNumbers')">Please enter numbers only.</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

The below validator only numbers only.
Try this, it may work:
`^[0-9]*$`