# Angular forms control stays VALID even with non numbers

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have:

```
<input
   type="number"
   formControlName="xyz"
```

and I have:

```
    this.reportForm.addControl(
        'xyz',
        new FormControl(xyz, [Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")])
    );
```

I only want it to accept numbers. But when I enter e.g. "2dddd" the value of the form control changes to null and the state of the formcontrol stays VALID.

Comment: If you use `type="number"`, when you input the character other than numeric, it will not be allowed. Example, when entering: "2dddd", it will only accept 2. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ojhsvw?file=src%2Fmain.ts). So I doubt what is your actual issue?

Comment: Firefox allows entering non numbers

Comment: Hmmm, can I know which Mozilla version you used? You may also refer to this [link](http://html5test.com/compare/feature/form.number.element.html) to see the browser version which support `<input type="number">`.

Comment: In case, you may look for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41465542/8017690) to implement the input with numeric only via Angular directive.

Answer (score 0):

From your snippets it appears that you are adding the controls dynamically, ie. at the moment the form is constructed and bound to the template, the control `xyz` does not exist yet. This might be the root cause. If this is the case you might have to run `this.reportForm.get('xyz').updateValueAndValidity()`.

The "static" approach (ie. when you declare the control in the construction phase) works fine for me, ie. I am not able to type `d`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="number" formControlName="xyz">
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  form = new FormGroup({
    xyz: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]),
  });
}
```

Don't be surprised though that the input of type number may accept the letter `e` (as part of exponential notation).